# Sharing a USB printer on a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, printer

I have a Nokia G140F ONT router with a USB port on it. I also have a USB-only printer and scanner Samsung SCX3400 that I would like to attach to it.

The problem is that the router (which supports print sharing) stubbornly asks me to set a username and password for the printer. None of the computers connected to my network are able to detect the printer, and nothing shows up when I enter the home gateway of the router. I tried following various troubleshooting methods online but to no avail.

I think it's also worth mentioning that the router sets up an FTP server if a USB storage device is connected to it instead of acting as a NAS. (accessible by typing in ftp://192.169.0.1). The router demands a username and password in this case too.

The router itself seems to be undetectable on my network, as none of my computers recognize it. Whenever I run Windows Diagnostics, it says that SMB is not supported or available. I then turned on SMB 1.0 from windows features, but to no avail.

The FTP settings:
[image: The FTP settings]

Printer sharing settings:
[image: Printer sharing settings]

Overview page of router settings:
[image: Overview page of router settings]

Comment: Could it be that the router sets up a new FTP server for the printer? However, I checked ftp://192.168.0.1 after connecting the printer, but Windows was unable to connect to the address.

Comment: Can you post a link to a good user manual (in English) for this device? I can only find a 9-page bare bones installation guide from the FCC submission, and it's less than useless. Or can you post screenshots of the admin UI regarding printer sharing? Which network printing protocols does this thing claim to support?

Comment: This router was provided for free by my ISP. There were no manuals given. No idea of the protocols it supports.

Comment: Did you try setting the username and password?

Comment: For security reasons, I doubt your router will allow you to do anything before you setup a username and password.

Comment: Yes, I have set up a usename and password.

Comment: The username and password are mandatory, I just don't know where to enter it to connect to my printer. No network-wide search reveals any network printer.

Answer (score 1):

After far too much searching and trial and error the following worked for me:

- Add printer or scanner
- The printer that I want isn't listed
- Select a shared printer by name
- `http://"ROUTER IP":631/printers/"DEVICE NAME"`

  - E.g. `http://192.168.1.254:631/printers/Brother_HL-L2320D_series_255`
- Select and install the appropriate driver
- Click on "Print server properties" in the right hand pane in Printers & scanners in Windows Settings
- Ports
- Change Port Settings (Administrator Button)
- Select your port (should be at the end of the list)
- Configure Port...
- Select "Use the specified user account"
- Fill in the Username and Password you set for Printer Sharing on your router
- Select "Use same security setting for all users"